# Cannot see image on stackstatus.net in environments where Tumblr is blocked

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images, stackstatus, firewall

On [stackstatus.net](https://stackstatus.net/), the image is invalid on the right part of the screen. You should update the image so it shows.

[image: Stack Exchange Status Page]

My school's firewall blocks Tumblr. Maybe you could make it so stack exchange hosts the image, not Tumblr?

Comment: [I can see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mubjV.png) - do you perchance have a firewall blocking Tumblr? (The image's URL is `https://64.media.tumblr.com/avatar_9eeb21a613ee_64.pnj`)

Comment: @bobble Oh! Thanks for telling me! My school's firewall blocks Tumblr.

Comment: The *entire site* is hosted on Tumblr (I get a banner warning me about Tumblr's use of cookies when I open it). I'm surprised you can open it at all, but more importantly, that means there's nothing Stack Exchange can do about this, short of hosting the site somewhere else.

Comment: Also, this "bug" can be easily reproduced by setting up a firewall that blocks Tumblr. So the status declined tag fits perfectly, SE isn't going to change their host only because some places block it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Stack Status site is no longer hosted on Tumblr, making this question obsolete.

Answer (score 15):

Our status blog is currently hosted on Tumblr and the image you reference is the avatar for our profile on Tumblr. That avatar is always hosted by Tumblr (by uploading an image there) and cannot have an external image linked there. That means there is nothing we can do if the image is being blocked by your firewall.

Comment: It doesn't look like my pfp is hosted on tumblr... I right-clicked and pressed view image and here was the url: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjO4C5ar-TogJLiEZTz7c2nYEjpby6tHkkS59VZnw=k-s48

Comment: @DaCuteRaccoon: I... don't see how your own profile picture is relevant. animuson is talking about the avatar shown on stackstatus.net. Since stackstatus.net is hosted by Tumblr, the avatar for that account must be hosted by Tumblr as well.